# Pegar uma variável da url, passa por method get laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

Como faço para está função pegar os valores da url passada por method get

```
 public function searchBy($nome, $situacao){
     $params['nome'] = array('value'=>'%' . $nome . '%', 'operador'=>'like');
     $params['situacao'] = array('value'=>$situacao, 'operador'=>'=');

     return $this->search($this->cliente, $params);
 }
```

Comment: Me parece que esse `$this->search` está bem propício a injeção de SQL. Por que não usa o Eloquent?

Comment: parece que esse `$this->search` é um método que ele passa só o model e os argumentos de dentro do `where()` do eloquent

Answer (score 2):

Você pode importar a classe `Illuminate\Http\Request` no seu *controller* e utiliza-la no seu método para receber os dados passados pela requisição para o seu *controller*, por usa rota:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function searchBy(Request $request){
    $params = [
        'nome' => ['value' => "%{$request->input('nome')}%", 'operador' => 'like'],
        'situacao' => ['value' => $request->input('situacao'), 'operador' => '='],
    ];

    return $this->search($this->cliente, $params);
}
```

Comment: `$request->nome` também dá certo no Laravel 5 pra cima.

Comment: Sim, da certo, mas como `imput()` é mais genérico e inclusive compatível com o laravel 6 (que vai remover a classe `Imput`).

Comment: Não funcionou meus códigos estão ai      public function search1(){

        return view('cliente.search')->with(['nome' =>'' ,'situacao'=> '']);
      }    public function searchBy($nome ,$situacao){

    

        $params['nome'] = array('value'=>'%' . $nome . '%', 'operador'=>'like');
        $params['situacao'] = array('value'=>$situacao, 'operador'=>'=');

        return $this->search($this->cliente, $params);

    }